# How to retain cell background color when importing data into another sheet using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to ask if there is a way to retain the color (column J) of cell column if it is colored into another sheet. The code seems to work but I lost the color format in column J (red).

Here's the code I am using:

```
function Extract(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NAME');
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheet1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc).getValues();
  var sheetBG = sheet.getRange(2,10,lr,1).getBackgrounds();
  
  var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NEWSHEET');
 
  var columnJ = "10";
  var red = '#f4cccc';  
  var data = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i <= lr - 1; i++) {
    if (sheetBG[i] == red ) {  
       data.push(sheet1[i]); 
  }}
  newSheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,17).setValues(data);  
}
```

Comment: You want to copy only the red colours from column J or every color in column J? According to your code I understand you want only red color but your question does not clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way you got the background colors you can set them in the new sheet by using [setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

```
newSheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,17).setValues(data);
newSheet.getRange(2,10,sheetBG.length,sheetBG[0].length).setBackgrounds(sheetBG); // new code
```

In case you want to copy only red values then do something like that:

```
var new_sheetBG=sheetBG.map(r=>r[0]==red?red:"#ffffff") // keep only red and make white the others
newSheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,17).setValues(data);
newSheet.getRange(2,10,new_sheetBG.length,new_sheetBG[0].length).setBackgrounds(new_sheetBG); // new code
```

Comment: Hi Marios, I am getting a syntax error here: var var new_sheetBG = sheetBG10.map(r=>r[0]==red?red:"#FFFFFF");

Comment: @JMMR... in your comment it seems you put `var` twice. Can you confirm that ? Also indicate the exact error message.

Comment: That was just typo but I only have one "var"...var new_sheetBG = sheetBG10.map(r=>r[0]==red?red:"#FFFFFF");

Comment: @JMMR... Can you indicate the error message you are getting ? Also have you enabled v8 run time environment? Show screenshot of your error and code .

Comment: It worked when I turned on the V8 run time environment but it did not copy over the color, I see random rows with colors and other are not. I did however find another way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Extract(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NAME');
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheet1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc).getValues();
  var sheetBG = sheet.getRange(2,10,lr,2).getBackgrounds();
  
  var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NEWSHEET');
 
  var red = '#f4cccc';  
  var data = [];
  var color = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= lr - 1; i++) {
   var columnJ = sheetBG10[i][0];
    var columnK = sheetBG10[i][1]
    if (columnJ == red && columnK == red) {
      data.push(sheetAR[i]);
      color.push(sheetBG10[i]);
    }
    if (columnJ != red && columnK == red) {
      data.push(sheet[i]);
      color.push(sheetBG[i]);
    }
    if (columnJ != red && columnK == red) {
      data.push(sheet[i]);
      color.push(sheetBG[i]);
     }
    }
   newSheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
   newSheet.getRange(2,10,color.length,color[0].length).setBackgrounds(color);
}
```